Parts of texture missing on Cycles render
I've seen other people having issues where they're missing textures on Cycles render, but in my case, it's only a part of the texture.
Below is what the texture looks like on material view and EVEE render;


And below is what it looks like on Cycles;

What could be the possible causes of this problem?

Hello, maybe overlapping faces, check in Edit mode

Definitely overlapping faces.

Ah, of course. Silly me, I didn't even think of checking the faces
